# Handicapé : politiquement correct

Tags: usage

Y a-t-il un mot ou expression qui a remplacé le mot **handicapé** (**personne handicapée**) comme par exemple **demandeur d'emploi** a remplacé **chômeur**, **gardien d'immeuble** a remplacé **concierge**,  **non-voyant** a remplacé **aveugle**, etc. ?

J'ai vu plusieurs variantes telles que **personne moins valide** ou bien **personne à mobilité réduite** mais je me demande laquelle est la plus répandue.

Comment: "Personne à mobilité réduite" est plus précis et ne recouvre qu'une partie des handicaps possibles (par exemple une personne aveugle ou malvoyante est affligée d'un handicap visuel). Dans le sens général, je ne crois pas qu'il existe d'euphémisme largement utilisé.

Comment: Aucun des exemples n'en est un. "Chômeur", "concierge" et "aveugle" sont des mots comme les autres. (Surtout "concierge"...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La plus répandue est sans aucun doute **"personne à mobilité réduite"** ou bien dans de plus rares cas **"personne à déficience physique"**.

Comment: Merci. Connaissez-vous si cette variante est répandue hors de la France ? En plus, par rapport à la France ces tournures politiquement correct sont répandues partout ?

Comment: Hors de France je ne sais pas. En France oui, ces tournures, surtout la première, sont très répandues.

Comment: Merci encore de votre réponse rapide. Du coup, je viens de voir un fiche de recrutement pour un poste enseignant du supérieur à Montréal. Le fiche emploi la tournure "personnes handicapées".

Comment: C'est emploie et pas emploi...

Comment: Au Canada, "*personne à mobilité réduite*" est très répandu et souvent utilisé.

Comment: "Personne à mobilité réduite" ou PMR ne représente pas tous les handicaps et ne représente pas seulement des handicaps. Quelqu'un en fauteuil roulant parce qu'il s'est cassé les deux chevilles au ski est PMR mais pas handicapé. Inversement en France le daltonisme est considéré comme un handicap mais un daltonien n'est pas PMR.

Answer (score 5):

La meilleure expression, utilisée notamment dans les administrations publiques françaises, est actuellement "en situation de handicap".

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que cela dépend du contexte. De manière générale, nous pouvons également dire qu'une personne *possède un handicap*.

> Marc possède un handicap au niveau de la main droite et du cerveau.
>
> Marc est handicapé de la main droite et du cerveau.

Le terme *personne à mobilité réduite* fait surtout référence aux handicaps réduisant la mobilité et ne couvre donc pas l'entièreté des handicaps.

Answer (score 1):

J'entends de plus en plus souvent *porteur de handicap* plutôt que *handicapé*. L'idée est que la première expression désigne une caractéristique d'un individu parmi d'autres alors que la deuxième a tendance à le définir entièrement.

Dans la presse, je vois aussi *en situation de handicap*.